# Оформление ссылки на источник

Tags: общие-вопросы, источники

Скажите, пожалуйста, как оформить в тексте, в конце предложения, ссылку на несколько источников? Перечень источников дан в конце текста. Можно ли так: предложение [3, 8, 9-12]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Предложение [3; 8; 9-12].**
Источник: *[Кулинкович Т. О. "Основы научного цитирования", ч. 1.2, п. 4](https://t2t.livejournal.com/78574.html)*.